# gsutil cp using -I and -r will copy all files into one directory

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a file (out2.txt) with a list of GCS file URLs including version numbers. I am trying to copy those files to a local directory while keeping the directory structure.

I tried this command:

```
    cat out2.txt | gsutil -m cp -r -I ./download
```

All files were copied to the same directory and the directory structure in the source bucket was lost.

The same thing happened if I removed the -r argument.

Is there a way to keep the directory structure while using the -I argument?

Comment: I am looking for something similar to GNU cp --parents, that will create the parent directories when copying a file.

Comment: Are you able to provide some example URLs?

Comment: There is a feature request for this on gsutil's open source page at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/372